# Rotate a vector around an axis in 3D space

Tags: c#, math, vector, rotation

Tried to solve through the rotation matrix, but it does not work
**Input:**
Ten reals:

1. ```
    The 3D coordinates of the vector.
   ```
2. ```
    The rotation angle in radians.
   ```
3. ```
    The 3D coordinates of a point of the axis.
   ```
4. ```
    The 3D coordinates of the direction vector of the axis.
   ```

The length of the direction vector is greater than 1e-8.

**Output:**
Three reals, the 3D coordinates of the vector after its rotation.

**Example:**

**Input:**
3.0 2.0 4.0 3.141592653 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
**Output:**
-3.0 2.0 -4.0
**My realization of Vector3:**

```
class Vector3D
        {
            public double X { get; set; }
            public double Y { get; set; }
            public double Z { get; set; }
            public double Length
            {
                get
                {
                    return Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z);
                }
            }
            public Vector3D(double x, double y, double z)
            {
                X = x;
                Y = y;
                Z = z;
            }
            public Vector3D()
            {
                X = 0;
                Y = 0;
                Z = 0;
            }
            public static Vector3D operator +(Vector3D w, Vector3D v) {
                return new Vector3D(w.X + v.X, w.Y + v.Y, w.Z + v.Z);
            }
            public static Vector3D operator -(Vector3D w, Vector3D v)
            {
                return new Vector3D(w.X - v.X, w.Y - v.Y, w.Z - v.Z);
            }
            public static Vector3D operator *(double a, Vector3D v)
            {
                return new Vector3D(a * v.X, a * v.Y, a * v.Z);
            }
            public Vector3D RotateVector(Vector3D axis, double angle)
            {
                Vector3D vxp = axis.Cross(this);
                Vector3D vxvxp = axis.Cross(vxp);
                return this + Math.Sin(angle) * vxp + (1 - Math.Cos(angle)) * vxvxp;
            }
            public Vector3D RotateAboutPoint(Vector3D pivot, Vector3D axis, double angle)
            {
                return pivot + (this - pivot).RotateVector(axis, angle);
            }
            public void Normalize()
            {
                var div = 1 / Length;
                X *= div;
                Y *= div;
                Z *= div;
            }
            public Vector3D Cross(Vector3D v)
            {
                return new Vector3D(Y * v.Z - Z * v.Y, - X * v.Z + Z * v.X, X * v.Y - Y * v.X);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Subtract the point of rotation from the vector
2. Rotate using a rotation matrix or whatever way you want.
3. Add the point of rotation to the result

In [C#] world the above is as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Rotates a vector using the Rodriguez rotation formula
/// about an arbitrary axis.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="vector">The vector to be rotated.</param>
/// <param name="axis">The rotation axis.</param>
/// <param name="angle">The rotation angle.</param>
/// <returns>The rotated vector</returns>
public static Vector3 RotateVector(Vector3 vector, Vector3 axis, float angle)
{
    Vector3 vxp = Vector3.Cross(axis, vector);
    Vector3 vxvxp = Vector3.Cross(axis, vxp);
    return vector + Sin(angle) * vxp + (1 - Cos(angle)) * vxvxp;
}

/// <summary>
/// Rotates a vector about a point in space.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="vector">The vector to be rotated.</param>
/// <param name="pivot">The pivot point.</param>
/// <param name="axis">The rotation axis.</param>
/// <param name="angle">The rotation angle.</param>
/// <returns>The rotated vector</returns>
public static Vector3 RotateVectorAboutPoint(Vector3 vector, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 axis, float angle)
{
    return pivot+ RotateVector(vector - pivot, axis, angle);   
}
```

with the driver code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Vector3 vector = new Vector3(3.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f);
    float angle = 3.141592653f;
    Vector3 pivot = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Vector3 axis = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    Vector3 result = RotateAboutPoint(vector, pivot, axis, angle);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    // <-3, 2, -4>
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've got 10 broken test from 11(((

Comment: You don't have an example where the pivot is _not_ `(0,0,0)`? The code above is correct for 3D rotations, so without more information on the test cases, it fails there is little more to be done.